# How to divide two elements in a list of objects?

Tags: python-3.x, list, object, lambda, divide

I have a list of objects (a list of list) that contains a string, and two floating point values. I have to use a lambda function to divide the two floating point values.
This is my sample data:

```
listOfObjects = [['I', 5, 9], ['Y', 7, 13],['O', 3, 32]]
```

My output should be the same list of objects with one more column that has value of 9/5, 13/7 and 32/3

```
listOfObjects = [['I', 5, 9, 1.8], ['Y', 7, 13, 1.85],['O', 3, 32, 10.66]]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
avgValueList = list(map(lambda x, y: y[2]/x[1],listOfObjects))
```

But this gives me an error :
`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Comment: What is `listOfObjects`? Add the definition to the question.

Comment: Hi @DYZ , Thanks for the comment. The listOfObjects contains one string and two floating point values. The first three print statements is an example for my data.

Comment: Please add a sample `listOfObjects` to the question. Your code sample must be reproducible.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my question to make the code reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
avgValueList = list(map(lambda x: x.append(x[2]/x[1]), listOfObjects))
```

Each element of your listOfObjects is the list with a string and two floats. When you map over the listOfObjects, each of those lists becomes the argument `x` to the lambda. That means that `x[0]` is the string, `x[1]` is the first float, and `x[2]` is the last float. So `lambda x: x[2]/x[1]` takes a list of 3 elements and divides the last element by the middle element. You don't need an additional argument to you lambda. Since you are wanting to append to the existing list, we should add `x.append` to the lambda like this: `lambda x: x.append(x[2]/x[1])`. Now the lambda will take a list of three elements, calculate the division between the last two elements and append that result to the end of the list before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses the `pandas` Python module.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    ['I', 5, 9],
    ['Y', 7, 13],
    ['O', 3, 32],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df['result'] = list(map(lambda x: x[2]/x[1], lst))
print(df)
```

You can access the `result` column by typing the 'df.result' or `df['result']`.

Comment: Thank you , but I am not allowed to use other libraries.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for pandas here.